# multiple file upload using mvc using jquery file upload plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

i want to upload multiple file.as this link.
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html.

But when i click the addfile in my .cshtml no uploaded preview display in my webpage.

Please Help.

```
 <!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
      <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
<tr class="template-upload fade">
    <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
    <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
    <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
    {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
    {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
        <td>
            <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</td>
    {% } else { %}
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
        <button class="btn btn-warning">
            <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
            <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
        </button>
    {% } %}</td>
</tr>
```

{% } %}

  i add this code in head section of my cshtmlpage .
how to check this code is work?

Answer (score 0):

you must have missed the ID attribute in BeginForm() in cshtml file.

Try Using

@using (Html.BeginForm("YYYY", "XXXX", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "fileupload" }))

Regards,
Malay Kothari